# Phonegap form doesn't send email only in App (works on browser)

Tags: php, android, forms, cordova, email

**Here is my project**: I'm currently developping a little application with Phonegap including a form. This form receive differents values (email, name, tel,...) and send me an email on submit.
**And here is my problem**: everything is working on differents browsers (from my computer, differents phones,...) BUT when I want to use the application ".apk", everything is working (I have the confirmation message in App) but I don't receive an email...

So, here is my differents files.

**HTML** (simplified):

```
<head>
    <!-- Differents lines for charset, css and title -->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
            $.support.cors = true;
            $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
        });
    </script>
</head>

...

<form id="atelform" return verifForm(this);" >
    <div id="group-nom" class="group">
        <input id="nom" name="nom" type="text" placeholder="Nom" required>
        <span class="bar"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="group">
        <input id="prenom" name="prenom" type="text" placeholder="Prénom" required>
        <span class="bar"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="group">
        <input id="envoyer" value="Faire ma demande" type="submit">
        <p id="contact-message"></p>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // On submit
    $("#atelform").submit(function() {
        // Values are sending to the PHP file
        $.post("http://my-domain.com/app_mail.php", $("#atelform").serialize());
        return false;
    });
});
```

**PHP**:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

// Variables
$nom = $_POST['nom'];
$prenom = $_POST['prenom'];
$to = "me@email.com";
$sujet = "From app";
$message = "Mister <strong>".$prenom." ".$nom."</strong> is awesome!.\r\n\r\n";

$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
$mail->Host = "my host";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Username = $to;
$mail->Password = "my-password";
$mail->SetFrom($email);
$mail->Subject = $sujet;
$mail->Body = $message;
$mail->AddAddress($to);

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Sent!";
}
```

And finally my **config.xml**:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="my-id" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" versionCode = "10">
    <name>My App</name>
    <description>
        My awesome description!
    </description>
    <author email="me@email.com" href="http://my-website.com">
        Me
    </author>
    <platform name="android" />
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="InAppBrowserStorageEnabled" value="true" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <icon src="www/img/icon.png" />
</widget>
```

Comment: So you are saying that the POST call works but your backend doesn't send an email? Are you saying your get back "Sent!" from that POST call?

Comment: My apologizes: it's working! I guess another function (which validate the form inputs) was in "conflict" with this function, because I have changed the validate function and now everything is working perfectly!